# Show same and different elements between two char vectors

Tags: c++, vector, char, array-difference

I'm new to C++ programming. I want to make a code that shows elements which two `char vectors` have and do not have in common.

I started by creating two `string` by `cin` and then pass them to vectors. But now I don't know how to compare the `char` elements of both `vector`s, or even how to get to those elements. I tried treating them as if they were `int` and using `set_difference`, but none of that worked.

I would love to hear any recommendations on how to complete my code.

Here is the part of my code that actually can run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
  
  string s1, s2;
  vector<int> diff;
  cin >> s1;
  cin >> s2;
 
  vector<char> v1(s1.begin(), s1.end());
  vector<char> v2(s2.begin(), s2.end());
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to pass strings to the vector, you can just use `c_str` (if you want `char*`) or strings itself because `std::string` is an array of chars

Comment: For instance if you want to compare the first char in v1 to the second char in v2 just do this `if(v1[0]==v2[1]) {// stuff}` Is that what you are trying to do? Are you unsure how to write the code to answer your question?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::set` or is this a task you are supposed to do just using vectors?

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have to create vectors - you can work on strings as well. Also, the vector containing different characters should contain `char`s, not `int`s, so:

```cpp
int main(){
  string s1, s2;
  vector<char> diff;
  vector<char> same;
  cin>>s1;
  cin>>s2;
  ...
```

Now, if you want to check if the characters in `s1` are different or same to `s2`, you have to compare each element in `s1` with each element in `s2`.

```cpp
for(const auto& it : s1) { // for each element in s1
  bool different = true; 
  for(const auto& jt : s2) { // for each element in s2
    if(it == jt) {
      different = false; // if the elements are same, note it
      break; // and break out of the loop
    }
  }
  if(different) { // if this character wasn't same as any in s2, add it to the diff vector
    diff.push_back(it);
  } else {
    same.push_back(it);
  }
}
```

At this point `diff` contains all elements of `s1` that `s2` doesn't contain and `same` contains common elements. You need to append elements of `s2` that `s1` doesn't contain, too.

```cpp
for(const auto& it : s2) {
  bool different = true;
  for(const auto& jt : s1) {
    if(it == jt) {
      different = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(different) {
    diff.push_back(it);
  }
}
```

This code snippet is very similar to the previous one - the only differences are that `s2` is now the outer loop and `s1` the inner one and elements that are same aren't added to the `same` vector as they have already been added there.

You may not be familiar with the `for(const auto& it : s1)` syntax. Here it is basically equivalent to `for(size_t it; it < s1.size(); ++it)` (but they are pretty much different in general). For more detail google "range-based for loop".

As you can see comparing two unsorted arrays (in this case `std::string`s, which are arrays of chars under the hood) is very inefficient. A much better container for this situation would be `std::set`. It has its downsides as well, for example the elements must not repeat (if you try to insert an already existing element, nothing hapens), yet it suits this case perfectly. Google std::set to use it consciously.
Final code:

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <iterator> // to use std::make_move_iterator
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string temp1, temp2; // create temporary strings, because you can't insert data directly to set with cin
  cin >> temp1;
  cin >> temp2;
  // move data from temporary strings to sets
  set<char> s1(make_move_iterator(temp1.begin()), make_move_iterator(temp1.end()));
  set<char> s2(make_move_iterator(temp2.begin()), make_move_iterator(temp2.end()));

  set<char> diff; // it also can be a set
  
  for(const auto& it : s1) {
    if(s2.count(it) == 0) { // if the element of s1 is not present in s2, insert it to diff
      diff.insert(it);
    } else { // if it is present, insert it to same
      same.insert(it);
    }
  }
  for(const auto& it : s2) {
    if(s1.count(it) == 0) {
      diff.insert(it);
    }
  }
  for(const auto& it : diff) {
    cout << it;
  }
  cout << "\n"
  for(const auto& it : same) {
    cout << it;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way i can split the elements that are different from each vector??                                       For example       input1: programming               input2: pouring                                                                                                                            input1 different elements:  a,m,                                                                                                               input2 different elements:  u,

Comment: @FrancoLopez Yes, just create two separate vectors/sets. In the first loop add elements that are different to the first vector/set and in the second loop add different elements to the second vector/loop. So in the first loop it'll be: `if(different) { diff1.push_back(it); }` and in the second one: `if(different) {diff2.push_back(it); }`.